# Multiple buttons on iPhone - Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am trying to put multiple buttons on an iPhone app with an function, only when I run the function the 2nd time , does the button show. It doesn't show the two buttons which I have configured it to run.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    let screensize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(screensize.size.height)
        blur()


        // add iphone 2 buttons
        let rect : CGRect = CGRectMake(100, 50, 200, 50)
        var rectObj = NSValue(CGRect: rect)
        showButton("Hello", rect: rectObj, redvalue: 1.0, greenvalue: 0.5, bluevalue: 0.5, alphavalue: 1.0)

        let rect1 : CGRect = CGRectMake(20, 50, 200, 50)
        var rectObj1 = NSValue(CGRect: rect)
        showButton("Good bye", rect: rectObj1, redvalue: 0.5, greenvalue: 0.5, bluevalue: 0.5, alphavalue: 1.0)
    }

    func showButton(title: String, rect: NSValue, redvalue : CGFloat, greenvalue: CGFloat, bluevalue: CGFloat, alphavalue : CGFloat)
    {

        var rectRestored : CGRect = rect.CGRectValue()
        button.frame = CGRectMake(rectRestored.origin.x, rectRestored.origin.y, rectRestored.width, rectRestored.height)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redvalue , green: greenvalue, blue: bluevalue, alpha: alphavalue)
        button.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func blur()
    {
        var blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
        blur.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(blur)
    }
```

Does addSubView overwrite it ? If so I have tried insersubview : index and that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the method in viewWillAppear insted of viewDidLoad, because in viewDidLoad you still may not have the appropriate frame for main view.

Comment: No that didn't work, I am just thinking is there a quicker way to show multiple buttons programatically.